# My lambda function is not returning bad request

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, response, bad-request

I am trying to enter an invalid password, or even throw an exception in my AWS Lambda project (note that this is not an AWS Serverless project). No matter what I do, the status is always 200:

Here is code:

[image]

Here is API Gateway:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have no other idea how to make this return bad request :(

Comment: Please don't post images of code, post your actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I already made it work, what the code needs to look like is something like this:

```
public APIGatewayProxyResponse TestAbcAsync(APIGatewayProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        var loginRequest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginRequest>(request.Body);
        return new APIGatewayProxyResponse
        {
            StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
            Body = loginRequest.Username,
        };
    }
```

Then the setup in API Gateway needs to have this checked:

[image]

The "Use Lambda Proxy Integration" should be checked

Answer (score 0):

You ARE returning a 200.   You need to return something like `NotFound()` or `BadRequest()`.  You are just returning some (valid) json.

Comment: As you suggested, I added the library Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc and changed the return value to return new BadRequestObjectResult(response) for IActionResult, still returns 200